# Comparison testing using karate tool

Tags: automated-testing, api, karate

I'm using karate tool for api automation testing. Is there a way to do comparison or A/B testing using karate - That's testing with 2 urls and making sure both return the same response..please help ..

Comment: That is not A/B testing.  It might be testing of A/B testing I guess.  A/B testing would have different content responses.  Need a ton more info to really help you here

Comment: The same service when hosted in 2 different servers say for example web logic and tomcat , i have to make sure both the hits return the same response when I migrate the service from one server to another  . Please let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: It helps if you would add more context to your question, not only here in the comments. And I think, as terminology goes, your are trying to setup a [regression test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_testing). With [A/B testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) something else is meant.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178810/comparing-two-rest-services-to-each-other/53168556

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this should be very easy with Karate. I suggest you don't over-engineer tests and make 2 requests in your test. Save the response of the first request.

Now all you need to do is perform a `match` of the first response - that it is equal to the second response.

And because Karate allows you to set some fields of the "expected" JSON as `#string` or `#notnull` etc, you can easily handle cases where ID-s and time-stamps will be different.

Also suggest you use StackOverflow for Karate questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/karate